# Install4j Project Build Failure

Tags: install4j

As you know we are working on GUI based Installer for Linux platform,we were working on 8.0.7 or 8.0.8 evaluation versions for entire development as now support for 8.0.7 and 8.0.8 is taken out we have downloaded 9.0 Evaluation Version, but builds are not getting failed with the same.

Stack Trace:

```
Cause: com.exe4j.a.d
       java.lang.NullPointerException
Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Stack trace:

```
com.exe4j.a.d: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.install4j.b.j.b(ejt:278)
    at com.install4j.gui.b.run(ejt:103)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.install4j.b.c.a.a(ejt:171)
    at com.install4j.b.c.a.a(ejt:142)
    at com.install4j.b.b.r.a(ejt:83)
    at com.install4j.b.b.c(ejt:305)
    at com.install4j.b.b.a(ejt:161)
    at com.install4j.b.j.a(ejt:561)
    at com.install4j.b.j.b(ejt:205)
    ... 1 more
```

Same project builds are getting successfully generated with 8.0.7 and 8.0.8 also if we create new dummy project with 9.0 builds are getting successfully generated as well.

And now as our evaluation period for 8.0.7/8.0.8 is over now we are not able to regenerate the evaluation keys for older versions and our project build not getting generated with 9.0.
Please help us out in this scenario

[image]

Comment: Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this NPE is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regression in 9.0 will be fixed in 9.0.1.